# Showing text inside a custom drawn circle on a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I want a way to make custom text appear inside the predefined circles a la screenshot:

[image]

Below is my code (in coffeescript) that is currently making the map display with the hardcoded circles:

```
# Country View // Stage 1 of 3
  madrid = new google.maps.LatLng(40.416798,-3.700178)
  barcelona = new google.maps.LatLng(41.383997,2.163154)
  cordoba = new google.maps.LatLng(37.888171,-4.779383)

  initialize = ->
    @_initCircle "madrid",
      center:madrid,
      radius:90000,
      strokeColor:"#00FF00",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,
      strokeWeight:2,
      fillColor:"#00FF00",
      fillOpacity:0.4

    @_initCircle "barcelona",
      center:barcelona,
      radius:55000,
      strokeColor:"#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,
      strokeWeight:2,
      fillColor:"#FF0000",
      fillOpacity:0.4

     @_initCircle "cordoba",
      center:cordoba,
      radius:40000,
      strokeColor:"#ff6702",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,
      strokeWeight:2,
      fillColor:"#ff6702",
      fillOpacity:0.4

  @googleMap.notifier.on 'map:settled', _.bind initialize, @

_initOverlay: (name, opts) ->
  @circle[name] = new google.maps.Overlay opts
```

Comment: Do you plan to keep using hard-coded circles and display your own text in them?

Comment: so what's your question?>